# When writing pandas to csv, how can I quote the field if it contains a specific character?

Tags: pandas, csv, export-to-csv

If I understand [csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=quote_minimal#csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) correctly, pandas [DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) quotes only the fields which contains any of the *delimiter*, *quotechar* or *lineterminator*.

However my CSV is then processed by a program that requires other characters to be in quotes, how can I do that without quoting everything with `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` or `QUOTE_ALL` ?

For instance how can I escape if there is a `\t` or `\r` ?

```py
> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4], "b": ["b1", "b\r2", "b\t3", "b4"]})
> df.to_csv(index=False)
```

This returns `'a,b\n1,b1\n2,b\r2\n3,b\t3\n4,b4\n'`

But I want field b of row 2 and 3 to be escaped: `'a,b\n1,b1\n2,"b\r2"\n3,"b\t3"\n4,b4\n'`